# Value imported can't be changed to a number

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using the function importhtml() on my Google Sheets  :
`=IMPORTHTML("https://fbref.com/fr/comps/13/Statistiques-Ligue-1";"table";3)`

The data are imported but some data are displayed "01.08" and the value is a date. The other values are ok if they contains big number like 1.93. How it's possible to change that and have only numbers and not displayed that value as a date ?
I try to change the format of the cell but the value became a number like 44455.

This is a screen of what I have

### Just with the importHTML without any cell formatting

[image: Before changing format]

### After I format the cell as brut text

[image: After formatting cell]

How can I have the value as a number so to display 1.08 and not 01.08 ( for Google SHeets this is a date )
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a fourth parameter, which stands for locale.

`=IMPORTHTML("https://fbref.com/fr/comps/13/Statistiques-Ligue-1";"table";3;"en_US")`

This solved the problem here, since it turns the decimal points into commas, not allowing GS to interpret it as date format.